# connect manager not responding to 'commit changes' or 'check for upgrades

Tags: magento

In connect manager 1.5.0  magento 1.6.2 my connect manager does not respond...
nothing happens when i push the buttons. Everything else seems to work.

So i tried installing  with Paste extension key to install: 
it goes to a separate window where i click proceed, then i get a new window
Checking dependencies of packages
Already installed: community/Klarna 4.0.10, skipping

It was working before, can someone help , anyone knows what happened?

ps i am on my live store where the setting is local (and always has been ) i guess

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you try installing `community/Klarna` extension and it is already installed you can see this message:

```
Already installed: community/Klarna 4.0.10, skipping
```

Use table of installed extensions for channel `community` to remove this extension. And than you can install it again.